# Which machine learning algorithm to use?!

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I have a training set which is set of essays written by students for a question. These essays are all scored by human evaluators with labels such as 1, 2 , 3 which is actually marks allotted for those essays. I want know whether to use regression or classification algorithm for machine learning purposes! My readings on Machine learning suggests me to go with classification algorithm but again should I go with numeric classification or nominal classification. I am thinking numeric - Am I correct?

Comment: [Occam's Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor). Try something simple to code first like a regression/perceptron. If that doesn't work, try something more complicated like a logistic regression. If that doesn't work try an support vector machine.

Comment: Thanks Alex. So the only way to decide on the best fit algorithm is trial and error? I am surprised. I thought there will be clear cut definitions on when to use a particular algorithm.

Comment: It all depends on what you are trying to measure and the kind of error you are willing to allow for. Some data is clustered nicely allowing for a multi-class perception or a linear regression. Other times, it's really mixed together so you need to unravel it something akin to a support vector machine. For something like this, perhaps a mixture of gaussians would be appropriate if you have strong but spread out clustering for each label.

Answer (score 1):

Since your labels are discrete, you are looking at a classification problem with text data. I recommend using Logistic Regression (LR) as implemented in [scikit-learn library](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) in Python.

You would need to construct  $A_{V\times D}$ term-document matrix where $V$ is the vocabulary size and $D$ is the number of documents. Thus, each column of $A$ is a document or a collection of word-counts (here we are assuming that words are exchangeable and only their counts matter). I recommend using standard text-preprocessing such as tokenization, stop-word removal and tf-idf smoothing. [Gensim library](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) implements many of these functionalities.

The input to your Lostigic Regression (LR) becomes an $(X,y)$ pair where $X=A^{T}$ (each row of $X$ is a document with $V$ features) and $y \in \{1,...,K\}$ is the label. Once trained, you can use LR to predict the label of a new document (pre-processed in the same way as the training data).

Comment: Welcome to mathSE. Seems like a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your input data is discrete and the output that you want will be discrete too, so you are basically looking at a classification problem. Now, there are four approaches you could take:

$1.$ Logistic Regression followed by ROC curve/Confusion matrix
$2.$ K-Nearest Neigbours
$3.$ Decision tree/random forest
$4.$ Naive Bayes

I would suggest going with Naive Bayes. Create a dictionary of vocabulary as Vadim suggested and then finding the probability $P(y=c_1/d=d_{test})=P(d=d_{test}/y=c_1)*P(y=c_1)$. Let us not worry about normalisation as we only want approximates. Then you know $P(y=c_1)$ is the probability of number of documents that belong to the class $c_1$, and $P(d=d_{test}/y=c_1)$ is product of all probabilities of a word in a document that belongs to a particular class $c_1$ as a document is a collection of words. You can find this by having a `count` variable which counts the frequency of words in a particular class present in the document.

We then apply logarithm on both sides, and solve!

Alternatively, you could just use Sklearn's random forest. Moreover, by Occam's razor, this should be a preferred approach to deal with text classification problem such as yours.